# How can I run a Django management command asynchronously?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I have a Django management command that I'd like to issue in an asynchronous manner (via the [`call_command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) function). The flow of my code looks something like:

1. User fills out a web form (or edits pre-existing values in a form).
2. User clicks the submit button, and I do some processing.
3. Once processing is done, I'd like to issue a management command **without forcing the user to wait for it to return**.

If the management command fails for some reason, I'm not too concerned (my logs will catch those cases), so allowing the user to proceed on their merry way is fine by me.

Is this kind of asynchronous call possible, and if so, how best can I do it? Is the `threading` library sufficient for this case? I'm aware of packages like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), but using something like that seems like tremendous overkill for something as simple as what I'm trying to do.

Comment: celery is very easy to setup and is used in production by many companies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats an easy one!

Just use [`django-rq`](https://github.com/ui/django-rq). Easy as a pie.

I, personally, use it for sending emails asychronously which otherwise user had to wait about 11s. Just made my life easier. Its lightweight and I love it!

Comment: This seems pretty dependency heavy. I'd need django-rq, rq, and Redis just to get things working, and the Redis setup appears to need a host of build tool dependencies just to compile!

Comment: Yes, but you can use redis as a cache backend as well. The same happens with `celery` (it also needs redis or rabbitMQ or something for the queue). You cannot avoid that. However, by installing `redis` you have a cache-backend for bonus!